# Почему вместо значений в поле date выводится код Да Винчи?

Tags: php

Имеется код PHP(спасибо за него @Denis640Kb, сильно сдвинул меня с места)

```
<?php include "php/array_master.php"; ?> 
            <select id="Polina" class="select-css">
                <?php foreach ($q as $key=>$value){
                echo '<option>'.$value[date].'</option>'; //Выводим даты в селект, ну или в другие параметры по желанию
                }?>
            </select>
```

&q - массив данных из БД ( при применении функции print_r($q) выдается "Array ( [0] => 7 [ID_date_polina] => 7 [1] => 2020-02-28 [date] => 2020-02-28 [2] => 14:23:00 [time] => 14:23:00 )", что соответствует данным в БД). Вопрос: почему при выводе данных в поле  я получаю набор цифр: 1 1 2 2 7 7, а не дату?

Comment: Подскажите, у Вас же несколько строк выводится из запроса `sql`? Чтобы получить значение даты, можно использовать `$q['date']` или `$q[1]`. Чтобы выводить несколько дат, то лучше сделать перебором.

Comment: Если функция print_r() предназначена для вывода всех данных из массива, то у меня явно что то пошло не по плану, так как выводится только одна строка (указанная в вопросе) хотя в БД их три. Перебором?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам необходимо выводить данные через `while`, чтобы получить все данные. 
Пример:

```php
<?php
$servername = "";
$username = "";
$password = "";
$db = "";
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $db);

if ($conn->connect_errno) { // Проверяем ошибки
    // Соединение не удалось.
    echo "Ошибка: Не удалась создать соединение с базой MySQL и вот почему: \n";
    echo "Номер ошибки: " . $conn->connect_errno . "\n";
    echo "Ошибка: " . $conn->connect_error . "\n";
    exit;
}

$today = date("d.m.Y"); // Формат даты делаем такой же как и в базе данных

$query = "SELECT * FROM `desavir_Полина` WHERE date >='$today'";
$q = mysqli_query($conn, $query); //Отправляем запрос

?>

<select id="Polina" class="select-css">
    <?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q)) {
        echo '<option>'.$row['date'].'</option>'; //Выводим даты в селект, ну или в другие параметры по желанию
    }?>
</select>
```